# Find number of lines in python functions without running it

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to create a tool that identifies the number of lines of code in each function in a given python file. However- I do not want to actually run the code which is required with something like the inspect library suggested in other posts.

Is there a pre-existing tool I can use to get the source code for each function, or even a given function within the plain text of a .py file? Or will I need to create some custom regex/code for this?

Edit : Want to clarify since people are suggesting a few things I have already tried. AST provides me the ability to find the function name- but not the number of lines of the function, nor the source for the function or anything else that would lead me to it (from what I can see). Inspect can do it, but requires running the code (unless I am misunderstanding something).

Comment: Isn't a .py file just a text file? Can't you read it with the file functions and read each line, scanning for the word 'def'?

Comment: You could try regex-ing for the `def`, colon, and indented block, or parse the code with abstract syntax trees

Comment: What makes you think that the `inspect` module requires running the Python code? It requires loading the code, but not executing it.

Comment: @jjramsey How do you "load" it?

Comment: @jjramsey perhaps I have some misunderstanding here- I thought that it would error out when inspecting if I do not have all of the required imports or for other errors caused by the code in a file not being meant to run standalone- is this not the case? I have the .py files which I am opening as plain text.

Comment: @KellyBundy Import the module with the source code in question. That may run *some* things, but not the functions defined in the source.

Comment: @jjramsey Yes, importing runs it, and they said they don't want to run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ast` module to walk through the parse tree of a Python program. This requires that the program not have any syntax errors, but it will not attempt to execute the program, so runtime errors won't hinder the process. (In particular, since it doesn't execute `import` statements, it won't descend into imported modules.)

The following very simple sample assumes that:

- By "lines", you mean the physical lines, as opposed to logical lines. (This code prints the start and end line numbers, but you could change that to `node.end_lineno - node.lineno + 1` if you just want the line count.)
- You want to list each function, including nested functions and class members. This code tracks (and prints) `class` blocks as well as `def` blocks, indenting nested objects by four spaces (or the value of the `indent` argument).
- You don't care about async defs. The only reason I left them out was to save space; there's really nothing special about them, and you would just have to add one more visit method to capture them.

```py
import ast
class ListVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, indent=4):
        self.cur = 0
        self.ind = indent
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        print(f"{'':>{self.cur}}Function {node.name} {node.lineno}->{node.end_lineno}")
        self.cur += self.ind
        self.generic_visit(node)
        self.cur -= self.ind
    def visit_ClassDef(self, node):
        print(f"{'':>{self.cur}}Class {node.name} {node.lineno}->{node.end_lineno}")
        self.cur += self.ind
        self.generic_visit(node)
        self.cur -= self.ind

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sys import argv
    v = ListVisitor()
    for fn in argv[1:]:
        try:
            with open(fn) as source:
                v.visit(ast.parse(source.read(), filename=fn, mode='exec'))
        except SyntaxError as e:
            print(e)
        except OSError as e:
            print(e)
```

Here's what the output looks like when I call it on itself:

```bash
$ python3.9 -m listfuncs listfuncs.py
Class ListVisitor 2->15
    Function __init__ 3->5
    Function visit_FunctionDef 6->10
    Function visit_ClassDef 11->15
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of node.lineno and node.end_lineno. This solves my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using AST module you can handle some cases, but there are many ways to have a function defined for a module. This example covers the case where the function is defined on the module itself.

```py
import ast
from other_module import f4 # this will not be available
def get_function_code(source, function_name):
    # iterate backwards as we are interested on the last definition
    for stmt in ast.parse(source).body[::-1]:
        if isinstance(stmt, ast.FunctionDef) and stmt.name == function_name:
            # maybe the function has decorators
            if len(stmt.decorator_list) != 0:
                start = min(d.lineno for d in stmt.decorator_list)
            else:
                start = stmt.lineno
            end = stmt.end_lineno
            return '\n'.join(source.split('\n')[start-1:end])
```

Usage example

```py
source = """import ast
class Class(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def f1(self):
        '''
        This is not a module function
        '''

def f1():
  '''
  This is a module function
  '''
@decorator
def f2():
  '''
  this is a function with a decorator
  '''

f3 = f1 # this cannot be retrieved without running the code
"""
print(get_function_code(source, 'f1'))
print('-------------------------------')
print(get_function_code(source, 'f2'))
print('-------------------------------')
print(get_function_code(source, 'f3'))
print('-------------------------------')
print(get_function_code(source, 'f4'))
```

Comment: From the question: "I do not want to actually run the code which is required with something like the inspect library suggested in other posts." This post recommends the very library that the question rules out.

Comment: heheh, I skip that during my diagonal scan. I see that you commented there, let's wait for the response. +1 for that!

Comment: Yeah I don't want to actually evaluate the code :/ This is something that would run outside the codebase as a github action

Comment: There you have the response you need.

Comment: Updated the post with a function taking the source code, so you can get the function say from something different than a file, e.g. a request response.

Answer (score -3):

A `.py` file is just a simple text file. You can read it as usual:

```
def count_lines(file_path):

    with open(file_path) as f:        # Open file
        lines = len(f.readlines())    # Read all lines, it's a list so you can use len()
        return lines                  # Return the number of lines

count_lines("./filePath")
```

1. Open the file as usual;
2. Read all the lines with `.readlines()` that return a list;
3. Use `len()` to get the length of the list that correspond to the total number of lines;
4. Return the number of lines.

Comment: I want to count the lines in each function, not the whole file.